# Words For Frequencies Less Than An Hour

Tags: time, frequency

I'm writing a scheduling module and need to show frequency options ranging from once a minute to once a year. Anything over an hour is pretty simple, but I'm looking a formal term for frequencies under an hour.

```
Every...   | Term
Year       | Annual
6 Months   | Semi Annual
3 Months   | Quarterly
1 Month    | Monthly
Week       | Weekly
Day        | Daily
Hour       | Hourly
30 Minutes | Semi Hourly (?)
15 Minutes | Quarter Hourly (?)
10 Minutes | Decminutely (?)
5 Minutes  | Pentminutely (?)
2 Minutes  | Biminutely (?)
Minute     | Minutely (?)
```

*If anyone has an idea for a better SE forum that this should be posted on please let me know*

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/